# Add maven dependencie from a separate project

Tags: java, maven

I have a question about maven multiproject build. There are maven projects:

```
root
|
|---libs
|    |
|    |---mailing
|    |      |
|    |      |---pom.xml
|    |        
|    |---utils
|           |---pom.xml
|
|---partner
     |
     |---admin
            |---pom.xml
```

*admin::pom.xml:*

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.com.parent.partner</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>admin</artifactId>
<name>admin</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<!-- dependencies and so on and so forth -->
```

*mailing::pom.xml:*

```
<groupId>my.com.mailing</groupId>
<artifactId>mailing</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<!-- dependencies and so on and so forth -->
```

How could I add dependency of admin form mailign?

Comment: It looks like you have different versions within your multi module build which is in contrary to the idea of a multi-module build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aSimply add it as dependency in mailing pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.com.parent.partner</groupId>
        <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hah, you're absolutely right. `mvn install`'s completed without any error. Thank you.